# Bounding the degree of the Weierstrass polynomial of a product of a holomorphic function and a polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

***In brief.*** For a fixed holomorphic function $v$, I want to bound the degree $q$ of the Weierstrass polynomial $Q$ in the Weierstrass decomposition $v^TP = uQ$, in terms of the degree $p$ of the polynomial $P$.

***In detail.*** Write points in $\mathbb{C}^{m+1}$ as $z = (x,y)$ with $x \in \mathbb{C}$ and $y \in \mathbb{C}^m$. Assume that $v : \mathbb{C}^{m+1} \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is holomorphic, and that $P : \mathbb{C}^{m+1} \to \mathbb{C}^n$ is a polynomial of degree $p$. The Weierstrass preparation theorem says that, in a neighborhood of the origin,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n v_k P_k = uQ,
$$
where $u$ is holomorphic with $u(0) \neq 0$ and $Q$ is a Weierstrass polynomial of degree $q$, i.e.
$$
Q(x,y) = x^q + \sum_{k=0}^{q-1} a_k(y) x^k,
$$
where each $a_k$ is holomorphic. Note that $u$ and $Q$ both have a "hidden dependency" on which polynomial $P$ is chosen.

***Question.*** For a fixed function $v$, as one varies $P$ across all polynomials, is it possible to bound the degree $q$ of the polynomial $Q$, in terms of of the degree $p$ of the polynomial $P$?

***Example with $n=1$.*** Let $v = uW$ be the Weierstrass decomposition of $v$, with $u(0) \neq 0$ and $W$ a Weierstrass polynomial of degree $w$. Then, $vP = uWP$ so $Q = WP$ and the degree of $Q$ is at most $w+p$, as desired.

***Example 2.*** If $v$ itself is a polynomial of degree $w$, then $Q = vP$ has degree $q=w+p$ again.

***Example 3.*** For a fixed degree $p$, denote the coefficients of $P$ by $P_1,\ldots,P_r$. Write $\phi(z,P_1,\ldots,P_r) = v^T(z)P(z)$, which is holomorphic in its arguments, and find a Weierstrass decomposition $\phi = uQ$. Technically, this decomposition is only valid near $P=0$, but $\phi$ is linear in $P$ so hopefully this is not an impediment. Then, denote by $q = q(p)$ the degree of $Q$ as a function of the degree $p$. My question would then be, can we find a bound for the growth of $q$?